# Running command within test statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a piece of code to find the first file in a directory:

```
bash~> $( echo eval "ls | head -1" )
arguprog.sh
```

This snippet was then added to an if statement, to run a different set of commands if that file was arguprog.sh:

```
bash~>  if [[ $( echo eval "ls | head -1" ) == "arguprog.sh" ]]; then echo "TRUE"; else echo "FALSE"; fi;
FALSE
```

However this is not doing what I want. It returns FALSE even though the first file is arguprog.sh!

Is there a way to resolve this while still doing the string comparison entirely within the test block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, `eval` is evil, especially when it's not needed. In your case, `eval` is *not* needed!

Replace the coding horror you showed with just:

```
ls | head -1
```

and to include it in your test statement:

```
if [[ $(ls | head -1) = "arguprog.sh" ]]; then echo "TRUE"; else echo "FALSE"; fi
```

But this is *wrong and broken* (see below).

Now something more general: *do not parse the output of `ls`*. If you want to find the first file (or directory or...) in your current dir, use globs and this method:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=( * )
# The array files contains the names of all the files (and directories...)
# in the current directory, sorted by name.
# The first one is given by the expansion of "${files[0]}". So:
if [[ "${files[0]}" = "arguprog.sh" ]]; then echo "TRUE"; else echo "FALSE"; fi
```

Notice that your method, parsing `ls` is *wrong*. Look:

```
$ # Create a new scratch dir
$ mkdir myscratchdir
$ # Go in there
$ cd myscratchdir
$ # touch a few files:
$ touch $'arguprog.sh\nwith a newline' "some other file"
$ # I created 2 files, none of them is exactly arguprog.sh. Now look:
$ if [[ $(ls | head -1) = "arguprog.sh" ]]; then echo "TRUE"; else echo "FALSE"; fi
TRUE
$ # HORROR!
```

There are twisted work-arounds for this, but really, the best method is the one I just gave you.

Done!

Comment: @davak `=` and `==` are actually equivalent within `[[...]]`. See [the end of this section in the bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions). Yet, I edited my answer so as to be more POSIX conform (but I don't really care about that), and so as to save one character: that can make a huge difference in a code-golf! Thanks `;-)`.

Comment: Wow this is quite a schooling for me, no idea that I'd opened a can of worms! Appreciate this :)

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$( echo eval "ls | head -1" )` is `"eval ls | head -1"` not `"arguprog.sh"`, hence why you get `FALSE`.

Take a look at this:

```
$ a=$( echo eval "ls | head -1" )
$ echo $a
eval ls | head -1
```

The reason you see `arguprog.sh` when you run `bash~> $( echo eval "ls | head -1" )` is because bash executes the command which is `eval ls | head -1` and returns the result which is `arguprog.sh`.

In order to do the same in your if-statement, you need to execute it as well by enclosing it in another set of `$(...)`, like this:

```
$ if [[ $($( echo eval "ls | head -1" )) == "arguprog.sh" ]]; then echo "TRUE"; else echo "FALSE"; fi;
TRUE
```

But don't do that! It is a lot easier to simply use:

```
$ if [[ $(ls | head -1) == "arguprog.sh" ]]; then echo "TRUE"; else echo "FALSE"; fi;
TRUE
```

Also note that parsing the output of `ls` is not good practice. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for details.

Comment: A lot easier... but broken (see my answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
 if [[ `ls | head -1` = "04 dynamic-programming.pdf" ]]; then 
      echo "TRUE"
 else 
      echo "FALSE"
 fi
```

You should merely use `=` instead of `==` and skip the `eval` part.

Comment: this does not work (and crash) if there is a space (or another annoying character) in the name of the first file

Comment: Changed. Thx for your notice :)

Comment: In fact, this doesn't look completely fixable when using `ls`, as explained by the link in dogbane's post... Bash annoys me sometimes :D.